# Sorting Matrix where column specifies condition next element needs to meet

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

Say I have a long table with elements

```
% table with distinct elements for A1. A2 is sometimes an integer and
% sometimes -1000 
T   A1    A2 
0   182 181
1   182 180
2   181 180
3   45  -1000
4   29  -1000
```

Separately, i have an array that specifies a different order for when  -1000 (in A2) needs to be present.

```
% array specifies whether A2 should have -1000 
 [True False True False False]
```

so for the example above the desired output is :

```
 T   A1    A2 
0   45  -1000   % array is true and first time -1000 appears 
1   182 181  % array above is false 
2   29  -1000 % second time -1000 appears 
3   182 180
4   181 180
```

Any efficient ways to do this?
Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one approach:

1. Get the indices of the rows where `A2 == -1000`, let's call this `neg` (for negative).
2. Take a copy of the table (`tblOld`), because we're about to override the original table in two steps and need to refer to it in the 2nd step.
3. - Override the `true` rows from the indexing array with the `neg` rows
   - Override the `false` rows from the indexing array with the *other* rows

```
idx =  [true false true false false];
neg = (tbl.A2 == -1000);
tblOld = tbl;
tbl( idx, 2:3 ) = tblOld( neg, 2:3 );
tbl( ~idx, 2:3 ) = tblOld( ~neg, 2:3 );
```

Output:

```
tbl =
  5×3 table
    T    A1      A2  
    _    ___    _____
    0     45    -1000
    1    182      181
    2     29    -1000
    3    182      180
    4    181      180
```